# Rewrite into single query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, subquery, correlated-subquery

I have to separate select queries I'm looking to combine in to one query.  Meaning I'd like my out put formatted like:

col 1 | col2

252  ----  05

One idea is to write a CTE and while these two are small queries I have about 4 more like this for date ranges which I thought to avoid using one or more CTES to get the data.

Here are my select queries:

```
SELECT 
  count(*) as pastDueRepl   
FROM TBLPTS_APPDATA 
WHERE APPV_PTSSTATUS = '2'      
  AND (APPD_NEXTREPLDATE IS NOT NULL)   
  AND APPD_NEXTREPLDATE between DATEADD(Day,-30,GETDATE()) and GETDATE()

SELECT 
  count(*) as pastDueInsp   
FROM TBLPTS_APPDATA 
WHERE APPV_PTSSTATUS = '2'      
  AND (APPD_NEXTINSPDATE IS NOT NULL) 
  AND APPD_NEXTINSPDATE between DATEADD(Day,-30,GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
```

Comment: Is it a typo, or are you really doing your date range check against `APPD_NEXTINSPDATE` for both queries?

Comment: typo i just made the correct thanks

Comment: Note that the filter on "is not null" is not necessary because you are also filtering on the same field elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `0` column to each query then `sum` over `union` of them:

```
SELECT SUM(pastDueRepl) as pastDueRepl, sum(pastDueInsp) as pastDueInsp  FROM(
  SELECT 
  count(*) as pastDueRepl   , 0 as pastDueInsp  
  FROM TBLPTS_APPDATA 
  WHERE APPV_PTSSTATUS = '2'        
  AND (APPD_NEXTREPLDATE IS NOT NULL)   
  AND APPD_NEXTINSPDATE between DATEADD(Day,-30,GETDATE()) and GETDATE()

  UNION ALL

  SELECT 
  0 as pastDueRepl, count(*) as pastDueInsp 
  FROM TBLPTS_APPDATA 
  WHERE APPV_PTSSTATUS = '2'        
  AND (APPD_NEXTINSPDATE IS NOT NULL) 
  AND APPD_NEXTINSPDATE between DATEADD(Day,-30,GETDATE()) and GETDATE()    
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
select case when APPD_NEXTREPLDATE is not null and APPD_NEXTINSPDATE is null then 'a'
when APPD_NEXTREPLDATE is null and APPD_NEXTINSPDATE is not null then 'b'
when APPD_NEXTREPLDATE is not null and APPD_NEXTINSPDATE is not null then 'c'
else 'd' end status
, count(*) records

from etc
where etc

group by case when APPD_NEXTREPLDATE is not null and APPD_NEXTINSPDATE is null then 'a'
when APPD_NEXTREPLDATE is null and APPD_NEXTINSPDATE is not null then 'b'
when APPD_NEXTREPLDATE is not null and APPD_NEXTINSPDATE is not null then 'c'
else 'd' end
```

The details depend on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I would use conditional aggregation and use the different conditions inside the aggregate function, so for every row matching the condition 1 is added to the sum (which functions as a count):

```
SELECT 
    SUM(
       CASE 
        WHEN APPD_NEXTINSPDATE between DATEADD(Day,-30,GETDATE()) and GETDATE() 
          THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
       END
    ) AS pastDueInsp,
    SUM(
       CASE 
        WHEN APPD_NEXTREPLDATE between DATEADD(Day,-30,GETDATE()) and GETDATE() 
          THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
       END
    ) AS pastDueRepl   
FROM TBLPTS_APPDATA 
WHERE APPV_PTSSTATUS = '2';
```

Or you could use the `union all` operator to merge the statements, or use each as a derived table or in a cte. So many options.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a good way to minimize the repetition and reduce the amount of times you have to hardcode your date range boundaries:

```
  with DateRangeBoundaries as (select DATEADD(Day,-30,GETDATE()) as LowerBoundDate,
                                      GETDATE() as UpperBoundDate)
select count(case when t.APPD_NEXTREPLDATE between drb.LowerBoundDate and drb.UpperBoundDate
                  then 'X' end) as pastDueRepl,
       count(case when t.APPD_NEXTINSPDATE between drb.LowerBoundDate and drb.UpperBoundDate
                  then 'X' end) as pastDueInsp
  from TBLPTS_APPDATA t
  join DateRangeBoundaries drb on 1=1
 where t.APPV_PTSSTATUS = '2'
```

The above may provide you with more compact syntax.  However, if you are relying on indexes on your date columns, then the above may actually hurt your performance. Make sure you profile this if you decide to try it.